# Moving a Bitmap with a Vector with onTouch on a canvas view

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, vector, bitmap

I am trying to figure out how to move a bitmap over a canvas view by using the input of my onTouch method.
As of now, my bitmap only moves in a 45° angle until one X or Y coordinates of my bitmap matches the fingertouch.
Does anyone know how I can change the speed of one of the X or Y cooridates so it will "fly" to the point where the finger is?
Thanks for your help :)

My onDraw():

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BackScaled,0,0,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bobScale,meX-bobScale.getWidth(),meY - bobScale.getHeight(),null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(grunScale,700,10,null);

    if(touched == 1 && meX<= pressX && fliegen == 0){   
        meX = meX+ (width /300);    
    }

    if(touched == 1 && meX >=pressX &&fliegen == 0){
        meX = meX- (width / 300);       
    }

    if(meX >= width -(width/6)){    
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawText("The door is closed", 600, 350, paint);
    }

    if(pressX >= 700 && pressX < 800 && pressY >= 10 && pressY <= 110){
        fliegen = 1;
    }

    if(meX<= pressX && meY >= pressY && fliegen == 1 &&touched ==1){
        meX = meX+4;
        meY = meY-4;
    }

    if(meX>= pressX && meY <= pressY && fliegen == 1 &&touched ==1){
        meX = meX-4;
        meY = meY+4;
    }

    if(meX >= pressX && meY >=pressY && fliegen == 1 && touched == 1){

    }
    invalidate();
}
```

onTouch:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){  

            touched = 1;
             pressX = (int)me.getX();
             pressY = (int)me.getY();       
    }

    if(me.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);{
        touched = 1;
        pressX = (int)me.getX();
        pressY = (int)me.getY();

    }
    if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        touched = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you need anything else to answer my question please don't hesitate to ask for it!

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial in a previous app I built. Try to really understand what he is doing and you will find your answer.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

Comment: hm, i have issues trying to understand what he does... do you have a simple fast explanation? :P